# Problem in using credentials in google disk api

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I’m using google disk api. I get disk credentials .I add file in project directory.Now I had a this error in code compilation. I copy pasted the code from google quick start.

```
     at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
     at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
     at googleapi.DriveQuickstart.getCredentials(DriveQuickstart.java:46)
     at googleapi.DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution, just change this:

```
InputStream in = DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

To :

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(" ");  
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

And compile using Gradle!